# How to invoke a delegate beginInvoke within a DBContext

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, delegates, dbcontext

I have a code like this

```
 using (SomeDBContext db = new SomeDBContext())
 {
     foreach (var r in someColection) 
        {
           MyDelegate.BeginInvoke(db, parm1, parm2, etc, null, null);
        }
 }
```

The problem is, the function that is fed to MyDelegate uses the db dbcontext passed to it, and since the delegate is run asynchronously the db context was closed while the function is trying to access the database. Could someone please help resolving this problem? Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

A Context is not thread safe,you will have problems if you try to use it
(Unfortunately sometimes you will not notice anything wrong... )

Anyway ,the best approach is to create a new Context inside your method which will solve your original problem

Comment: Thank you! yes I was afraid of this. I know I can create new context inside the method, but then I would end up instantiating a bunch of context for the parallel threads, which I was trying to avoid. So it looks like the option is either using a bunch of context (1 per thread), or, not use delegate for this case. Is that about right?

Comment: @Yogi  context instantiation is very cheap,don't be afraid to create one per thread